# Chrome: How to find out who loaded a Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am running an application that includes JQuery 2.1.0 but I'm seeing `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead` coming from jquery-1.8.1.min.js. Thing is, I don't include that version of JQuery and I can't figure out who is including it. I don't see it getting loaded by Chrome's Network tab even after cleaning the browser cash and forcibly reloading the page.

Does Chrome provide a mechanism for finding out who each file in a particular application?

Answer (score 3):

A second after posting this question, I figured it out.

If you hover the mouse on top of the filename in the Developer Console, it will tell you where it was loaded from. It turns out the jquery-1.8.1.min.js was being loaded by a browser extension.

I'm going to leave this question open a bit longer though because I'm still interesting on how to solve this problem more generally (finding out *who* loaded a file, not where it's loaded from).